# Email CSV Attachment receives empty in Outlook 2013

Tags: php, email, cakephp, csv, outlook

I have received No Data CSV attachment email in Outlook 2013 only but got a CSV with data on gmail and other mails.
I have used the following CakePHP code:

```
            $this->Email->reset();
            $fileatt = ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS;
            $this->Email->to =array('ram@xyz.com');
            $this->Email->cc =array('ram@gmail.com');
            $this->Email->subject = "CSV mail";
            $this->Email->from = "info@gmail.com";
            $this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
            $this->Email->filePaths  = array($fileatt);
            $this->Email->attachments =array("Sample.csv");
            $this->Email->charset = "utf-8";
            $this->Email->headerCharset = "utf-8";
            $message = "Hi Thanks!";
            $this->Email->send($message);
```

Help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

> You should use this code in attachments

```
     $Email->attachments(array(
            'Sample.csv' => array(
                'file' => WWW_ROOT.'img/doc/Sample.csv',
                'mimetype' => 'text/csv',
                'contentId' => 'my-unique-id'
            )
         ));
```

Comment: This is not works, i have received the csv file in other mail services (gmail,yahoo) but still received the empty csv file for outlook 2013. Is that issue on outlook 2013 ?